# Resizing and positioning text and image inside another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have spent hours to do the following things but not working.

1.When you resize the window the small icon (`volklensset_90x90.jpg`) inside the div box should also move with the container. Currently it is staying outside of the main div if you resize the browser. Seems the icon is fixed somehow.

2.The small icon (`volklensset_90x90.jpg`) is not resizing though the `max-width` is `100%`.

3.I want to resize the text when you resize the browser.For this, I was using a jquery plugin from http://fittextjs.com/ but didn't work for me.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="home_box">
        <img width="376" height="380" 
             src="http://www.ukflooringdirect.co.uk/public/images/products/Br%20Ash%203%20strip%20Laq%20DET.jpg">
        <img width="90" height="90" 
             src="http://www.keeler.co.uk/images/products/thumbs/volklensset_90x90.jpg" 
             alt="icon_newwork" class="icon">
        <h4>hot off the server</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/EP4mj/

Important thing is I cannot keep the main big image as background image for the div home_box.

Is there any way? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering only the first question.

> When you resize the window the small icon (volklensset_90x90.jpg) inside the div box should also move with the container. Currently it is staying outside of the main div if you resize the browser. Seems the icon is fixed somehow.

Your icon gets positioned relative to `.container`. So when you resize your window `.container` gets wider and icon moves to the left. You can position the icon relative to `.home_box` by adding `position: relative` to it. You can center the `.home_box` by something like `width: 400px; margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: Thanks vbo that is working now.Any idea for 2nd one?

Comment: Please clarify this a bit. What kind of resizing do you need? It's something like width=50% for the image? Maybe use photoshop to create a visual representation of your idea if words is not sufficient.

Comment: It should resize according to the main big image.Do I need to use any kind of jquery or js? Thanks.

Comment: Best way is to scale according to the parent element. Just use `height: 30%` or something. You need to remove your `width="90" height="90"` attributes to hold aspect ratio.

Comment: You are a star!!.. Thank you so much.I can handle the 3rd one via jquery. Once again thanks a lot.I should have accept this answer 100 times if given a chance by stackoverflow.